# What's the simplest/easier way to do a health check/smoke test in an internal web app?

Tags: testing, automation, health-monitoring, smoke-testing

I have an intranet web application and I would like to do a simple health check/smoke that runs once an hour to make sure that everything is how it is supposed to be.

The tests are supposed to do some requests and check response for text and in some cases do one or two POSTs to see if the application in answering like it should.

I thought about using Selenium or Visual Studio's WebTest and schedule the run via CC.NET or another CI application but seems like a big shot for a simple thing.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is a good option. So is [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I dare to say that [SWAT](https://github.com/melezhik/swat) could be a good choice for you. It does exactly what you say - makes various http calls and check data returned, also it is possible to pass the test results to different report systems, using [TAP](https://testanything.org/) format which swat is compliance with. And finally there is a simple DSL to write such a checks.

Regards, the author.